# Subquery with a count and a limit issue

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have a subquery which counts track_id as follows

```
SELECT track_id, COUNT( * ) 
FROM  track_comments 
GROUP BY track_id
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

What I want to do is run a query based on the `track_id`s received from this query. How can this be done?

Comment: not clear add more brief

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
where track_id in 
(
    SELECT track_id
    FROM track_comments 
    GROUP BY track_id 
    ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC 
    LIMIT 10
)
```

Comment: I guess for small data it works but not for huge,performance lack

Comment: @KernElliott: Yes, it will.